# Join Table B to Table A only if entry in Table B equals entry in Table C

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables. clients, sales and potential_sales.
The basic structure is as follows:

Clients Table:
`+-----------+-------+----------------+
| client_id | name  |    address     |
+-----------+-------+----------------+
|         1 | john  | 12 blue ave    |
|         2 | paul  | 34 green lane  |
|         3 | peter | 69 yellow road |
+-----------+-------+----------------+`

Potential Sales Table:
`+----------+------------+---------------------+
|product_id | client_id  | received_free_promo |
+-----------+------------+---------------------+
|         3 |          1 |                   1 |
|         4 |          2 |                   0 |
|         5 |          2 |                   1 |
+-----------+------------+---------------------+`

Sales:
`+----------+-----------+-----------+
| sales_id | client_id | product_id |
+----------+-----------+------------+
|        1 |         2 |          4 |
|        2 |        43 |          4 |
|        3 |         2 |          5 |
|        4 |        18 |         93 |
+----------+-----------+------------+`

I want to join clients and potential_sales tables **ONLY IF**
1) received_promo equals 1 AND
2) they actually bought the promo package (i.e. the product_id for the potential sale has an entry into the sales table ). If they didn't eventually buy the free_promo product then I do not want to join the clients and potential_sales table at all. This is important - I can't simply `JOIN` to figure it out because this is only a small part of a bigger query and I can't afford to JOIN for no reason.

(Here is how I would like it to work. It's mainly pseudo-code to describe what I want to happen)
`SELECT
    c.* 
FROM
    clients c
    LEFT JOIN potential_sales ps ON ps.client_id=c.id
    LEFT JOIN sales ps ON s.product_id=ps.product_id
    IF(s.sales_id) JOIN potential_sales ps ON ps.client_id=c.id`

How do I do this in MySQL? I haven't come close to a solution. Please help!

Comment: let us see what you have tried out in SQL. Anyway, you only need SELECT AND JOIN, no need of UNION

Comment: "I have been trying out various things" - but you're not going to tell us what they were? Just join the three tables together.

Comment: @symcbean is that what the downvote is for? I explained that I didn't come close to a solution so didn't think it helpful to show my sql. I'll edit to show some of my work. hang on.

Comment: @symcbean can't join - I explained that if product_id in potential_sales don't match any product_id in sales, then I don't want to join at all. This is because this is only a small part of a bigger query and I can't afford to JOIN for no reason..

Comment: @Ben: IT'S STILL JUST A JOIN. Don't use left joins unless you know why you are using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.*, B.product_id, B.received_free_promo
FROM Clients A JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM PotentialSales 
     WHERE received_free_promo=1) B
ON A.client_id=B.client_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Sales C
                 WHERE A.client_id=C.client_id 
                      AND B.product_id=C.product_id);
```

See [**Demo on SQL Fiddle**.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e60429/5)

Comment: excellent! thanks so much! I still need to run a few more tests on it before I accept this answer but it's holding up well.. Any idea why the downvotes on my question?

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is the `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT
    C.*,
    P.*
FROM
    Clients AS C
    INNER JOIN PotentialSales AS P ON C.client_id = P.client_id
WHERE
    P.received_free_promo = 1 AND
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            'the client already sold that product'
        FROM
            Sales AS S
        WHERE
            S.client_id = C.client_id AND
            S.product_id = P.product_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..." select * from client as c natural join potential as p join sales as s on p.product_id = s.product_id where received_promo = 1". select * will mention everything from all the 3 tables. You can choose what you want as the result.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for the attempt. Secondly, please make your answer more readable using spacing conventions and the markdown that [stackoverflow provides](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Thirdly, I specifically said that I can't use a straight out `JOIN` which it seems that that's what you are doing.